# JRedisGraphCompileTimeException: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: errMsg:

Tags: java, redis, cypher, redisgraph, redislabs

I am creating Cypher query from my java program and passing that raw query to RedishGraph.Query() method. I am getting the following exception:

```
"com.redislabs.redisgraph.exceptions.JRedisGraphCompileTimeException: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: errMsg: Invalid input 's': expected DETACH DELETE, DELETE, DROP INDEX ON or DROP CONSTRAINT ON line: 1, column: 2, offset: 1 errCtx: dsspfnSpouseFname=" errCtxOffset: 1"
```

When I try to execute the same raw query in CLI/Redis Insight, successfully executing without any errors. Can some one help me what exactly this exception refers to.

Using Redis 5.0.6 version, JDK 11 and jredisgraph 2.0.2 version.

Comment: Can you please add the query you're trying to run?

Comment: My query contains some special characters, which we cannot able to see in notepad but we can able to see those special characters when we copy the query into MS Word document. I have removed those special characters and now working fine. Thanks!

Comment: It will be great if you can open an issue on github